# Android - avoid multiple items on a listview and remove items properly from the data base

Tags: java, android, listview, items

In one fragment of the application I add items to the database(Cart class) and catch the editText in of the listview in the following way(just the `getView()` method):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                           .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_product, null);

final Button addToCart = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_addToCart);
                addToCart.setTag(position);

addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Fetch product id
                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                // Fetch amount of product
                LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                EditText editText_amount = (EditText) rowLayout
                        .findViewById(R.id.editText_amount);
                try {
                    int amount = Integer.parseInt(editText_amount.getText()
                            .toString());
                    String k = Integer.toString(amount); 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),k,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Cart.AddToCart(products.get(position), amount);

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
```

the Cart class ( the database) :

```
public class Cart {
static HashMap<Integer, JSONObject> products = new HashMap<Integer, JSONObject>();

public static void AddToCart(JSONObject product, int amount) {
    int product_id;

    try {
        product_id = product.getInt("product_id");
        product.put("product_id", amount);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    products.put(product_id, product);
}

public static void ExcludeFromCart(JSONObject product, int amount) {
    int product_id;

    try {
        product_id = product.getInt("product_id");
        product.put("product_id", amount);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    products.remove(product_id);
}

public static JSONObject[] GetProducts()
{
    return products.values().toArray(new JSONObject[products.size()]);
}
}
```

and the fragment that populates and handles the listview of the added items in the Cart class (just the `getView()` method):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewGroup p=parent;
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_cart, null);
Button remove = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Fetch product id
                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                String k = Integer.toString(position);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),k,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Fetch amount of product
                LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                EditText editText_amount = (EditText) rowLayout
                        .findViewById(R.id.editText_amount_cart);
                try {
                    int amount = Integer.parseInt(editText_amount.getText()
                            .toString());

                    Cart.ExcludeFromCart(products.get(position), amount);
                    v.invalidate();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return;
                }

            }
        });
```

The problem is that occasionally ( not always , what makes it more strange) I can add multiple items to the Cart ( I want to avoid that of course ) and when I press the remove button , nothing happens( the items of the listView are not removed) . 
Will be grateful for Your assistance !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to incorrect use of the `convertView`.
Your code assumes that the `convertView` passed to `getView` matches the `position` parameter which is an incorrect assumption.

To verify this assumption, can you replace (in both getViews) the `View v = convertView;` with `View v = null;`? (and hence your not using the convertView)

If this works correctly, then I would suggest to put everything after the vi.inflate (in both getViews) outside the surrounding if statement. Hence you are setting the tag to the correct value again.